# How to redirect request at the haproxy level to fetch file from CDN?

Tags: haproxy

For a given url pattern, I want the contents of the file to be fetched from a CDN and not from my web server.

example:

```
www.example.com/some/path/ford/new?a=1&b=2
```

I need to extract:

ford
new
1
2

I want to fetch the file from the s3 (or CDN) like:

```
example-com.s3.com/customers/ford.new.1.2.html
```

Is this possible at the HAProxy level or would I have to do this in nginx somehow?

The earlier in the pipeline the better obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I remind having had to deal with something similar once, I believe the principle
was the following :

1) from the frontend, match the URL using an ACL and go to a specific backend
  2) in this backend first rewrite the URL using reqirep
  3) then perform the redirect with "redirect ... prefix /" which will reuse the
     same URL.

However in your case I see a host name, and the host name is not part of the URI
line, so it's not possible to make it appear there (not possible to combine two
lines yet). But maybe you don't need that many hosts and can live with a few rules ?